# how to find index where two matrices are different in Julia

Tags: julia

My problem is:
I have two large matrices: Matrix A is of rank 5 (namelly a Tensor), which I reshape to a Matrix B (NxM) of rank 2. At some point, my problem involved normalizing my matrices, so I was doing: 
1) A*norm_scalar;
2) reshaping A to get B.

which is giving a different result than doing
1) reshaping A to get B
2) B*norm_scalar;

Both results should have the same output, as I am only multiplying by a scalar. My theory is that there is something related to rounding precision. If so, which one is the most recommended way to proceed?

In this sense, I was trying to get B with both methods, namelly B1 and B2 and compare them:
I have tryed:

julia> isequal(B1,B2)
false

So, yes, they are different.

I know that find(B1.==B2) will give me the indexes where B1 and B2 are equal. Now: Is there any command that gives me the indexes where B1 and B2 are different?. this would help me great deal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find(B1.!=B2)` should do what you want.

Comment: on Julia 1.0 it is `findall`

Comment: This answer was automatically tagged "low quality". As explained in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ("Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."), please edit your answer to tell the OP what he's doing wrong, how you reasoned and what your code is about, to show that you understood the question and to make benefit both the OP and future visitors.

Comment: @Oscar Smith, Thanks, it works!!. PD: It would be nice to have the "coordinates of the index", as in rows and columns, but I guess I can find some way to achieve that!

Comment: I decided on such a short answer because OP mentioned `find(B1.==B2)`, implying that OP already knows about the find function and dotted operations for applying functions index wise. Given this, it seemed appropriate to keep the answer short and to the point.